# Alternatives for [variable = string substitution] in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am learning bash and trying to understand the different ways of making a substitution *and assigning it to a variable*.

Specifically, I'm changing Unix slashes ('/') to Windows ('\').

References:

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615217/bash-bad-substitution*
- https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/manipulate-text-from-the-command-line-with-sed
- http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2012/06/bash-script-find-and-replace-string.html

With thanks to Seth and terdon.

---

*Updated version. Original at bottom.*

```
#!/bin/bash
origPath="/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py"

path=$origPath
path=${path//\//\\}                      #Works
echo "Via bash (2-slash, no-g): $path"

path=$origPath
path=${path//\//\\}                      #Works
echo "Via bash (no dollar): $path"

path=$origPath
echo "${path}" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'     #Works, but don't know how to assign to var
#echo "Via sed (slash, quotes): $path"

path=$origPath
path=$(echo "$path" | sed s/'\/'/'\\'/g)   #Works
echo "Via sed (slash, quotes): $path"

path=$origPath
path=$(echo $path | sed s:'\/':'\\':g)   #Works
echo "Via sed (colon, quotes): $path"

path=$origPath                           #This and all following are
path=sed 's:/:\\:g' <<<$path             #s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
echo "Via sed/<<< (colon): $path"

path=$origPath
path=sed 's/\//\\:g' <<<$path
echo "Via sed/<<< (slash): $path"

path=$origPath
path=sed 's/"\/"/"\\":g' <<<$path
echo "Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): $path"
```

Output:

```
$ bash ./initial_script3.sh
Via bash (2-slash, no-g): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
Via bash (no dollar): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 13: ${echo "${path}" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'}: bad substitution
Via sed (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 25: s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 29: s/\//\\:g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 33: s/"\/"/"\\":g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
```

Output with debugging:

```
$ bash -x ./initial_script3.sh
+ origPath=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via bash (2-slash, no-g): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via bash (2-slash, no-g): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via bash (no dollar): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via bash (no dollar): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ sed -e 's/\//\\/g'
+ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
++ sed 's/\//\\/g'
++ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
++ sed 's:\/:\\:g'
++ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's:/:\\:g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 25: s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's/\//\\:g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 29: s/\//\\:g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's/"\/"/"\\":g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 33: s/"\/"/"\\":g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
```

---

*Original*

Below is what I've tried. Unfortunately, I can only get one method to work (sed with a pipe *and* quoting each element). The first one was working, I swear, and now it's not.

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
#!/bin/bash
origPath="/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py"

path=$origPath
path=${$path/\//\\/g}                    #WAS working, now not
echo "Via bash: $path"                   # ${$path/\//\\/g}: bad substitution

path=$origPath
path=${path/\//\\/g}                     #Bad output:
echo "Via bash (no dollar): $path"       #'\/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'

path=$origPath
path=$(echo $path | sed s/'\/'/'\\'/g)   #Works
echo "Via sed (slash, quotes): $path"

path=$origPath
#path=$(echo $path | sed s/\//\\/g)      #No error, but output=input
echo "Via sed (slash): $path"

path=$origPath
path=$(echo $path | sed s:'\/':'\\':g)   #Works
echo "Via sed (colon, quotes): $path"

path=$origPath
path=$(echo $path | sed s:\/:\\:g)       #sed: -e expression #1, char 7:
echo "Via sed (colon): $path"            #     unterminated `s' command

path=$origPath                           #This and all following are
path=sed 's:/:\\:g' <<<$path             #s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
echo "Via sed/<<< (colon): $path"

path=$origPath
path=sed 's/\//\\:g' <<<$path
echo "Via sed/<<< (slash): $path"

path=$origPath
path=sed 's/"\/"/"\\":g' <<<$path
echo "Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): $path"
```

Output:

```
$ bash ./initial_script3.sh
./initial_script3.sh: line 5: ${$path/\//\\/g}: bad substitution
Via bash: /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
Direct echo: \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
Via bash (no dollar): \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 14: \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py: No such file or directory
Via echo bash (no dollar): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
Via sed (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
Via sed (colon):
./initial_script3.sh: line 34: s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 38: s/\//\\:g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 42: s/"\/"/"\\":g: No such file or directory
Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
```

Output with debugging:

```
$ bash -x ./initial_script3.sh
+ origPath=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
./initial_script3.sh: line 5: ${$path/\//\\/g}: bad substitution
+ echo 'Via bash: /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via bash: /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ echo 'Direct echo: \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Direct echo: \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
+ echo 'Via bash (no dollar): \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via bash (no dollar): \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=echo
+ '\/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
./initial_script3.sh: line 14: \/ghome/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via echo bash (no dollar): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via echo bash (no dollar): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
++ sed 's/\//\\/g'
++ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via sed (slash, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ echo 'Via sed (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
++ sed 's:\/:\\:g'
++ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path='\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
+ echo 'Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py'
Via sed (colon, quotes): \home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
++ sed 's:/:\:g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
++ echo /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=
+ echo 'Via sed (colon): '
Via sed (colon):
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's:/:\\:g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 34: s:/:\\:g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (colon): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's/\//\\:g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 38: s/\//\\:g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (slash): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
+ path=sed
+ 's/"\/"/"\\":g'
./initial_script3.sh: line 42: s/"\/"/"\\":g: No such file or directory
+ echo 'Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py'
Via sed/<<< (slash, quotes): /home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py
```

Comment: `echo ${origPath//\//\\}`

Comment: @Cyrus Updated my script with that near the top. It gives incorrect output. :(

Comment: @aliteralmind, note carefully there are 2 leading `/` and no trailing `/g`: `echo "${origPath//\//\\}"`. `//` to replace all, `\/` to search for a slash (escaped to not clash with ->), `/` to separate the search and replace test, ``\\`` to substitute a backslash. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: //\//\\ != /\//\\/g

Comment: With sed: `echo "${origPath}" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'`

Comment: Sorry @Cyrus. Too many things happening today. Still two things I don't understand: How is the echo/pipe/sed version assigned to a variable, and how to get the `<<<` version to work? (Updated question.)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With "Parameter Expansion":

```
origPath="/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py"
path="${origPath//\//\\}"
echo $path
```

Output:

```
\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
```

---

With a pipe, sed and "Command Substitution":

```
origPath="/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py"
path="$(echo "${origPath}" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g')"
echo $path
```

Output:

```
\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
```

---

With sed, "Here String" and "Command Substitution":

```
origPath="/home/django_auth_lifecycle/urls.py"
path="$(sed -e 's/\//\\/g' <<< "${origPath}")"
echo $path
```

Output:

```
\home\django_auth_lifecycle\urls.py
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Learned a lot today. One more question: Can you show how to use alternative delimiters with the parameter expansion version? (Like `path="${origPath::\/:\\}"`.

Comment: This is not possible. [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) has no alternative delimiters for search and replace like sed. If you use two `:` then you can make "Substring Expansion" like this: `a="highway"; echo "${a:4:5}"`. Output: way

Comment: I wrote about this on my blog: http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/bashcrash